# Automatically generate conf file during make

Tags: bash, automation, sed, makefile

I have a conf file that is of the format:

name=value

What I want to do is using a template, generate a result based on some values in another file.

So for example, say I have a file called PATHS that contains

```
CONF_DIR=/etc
BIN_DIR=/usr/sbin
LOG_DIR=/var/log
CACHE_DIR=/home/cache
```

This PATHS file gets included into a Makefile so that when I call make install the paths are created and built applications and conf files copied appropriately.

Now I also have a conf file which I want to use as a template.

Say the template contains lines like

LogFile=$(LOG_DIR)/myapp.log
...

Then generate a destination conf that would have

LogFile=/var/log/myapp.log
...
etc

I think this can be done with a sed script, but I'm not very familiar with sed and regular expression syntax.  I will accept a shell script version too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely go with autoconf here, whose very job is to do this. You'll have to write a conf.in file, wherein all substitutions are marked with @'s, e.g.

```
prefix=@prefix@
bindir=@bindir@
```

and write up a configure.ac, which is a shell script that will perform these substitutions for you and create conf. conf is subsequently included in the Makefile. I'd even recommend using a Makefile.in file, i.e. including your snippet in the Makefile.

If you keep to the standard path names, your configure.ac is a four-liner and has the added advantage of being GNU compatible (easy to understand & use).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [using m4](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5594) as a simple template language instead.

Comment: Since you got me looking at m4, I then starting looking at the autotools.  Maybe I can hook into that? any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I think m4 is the way to go and generate with autotools.  Just need to work out how.  I'll ask that as a separate question.

Comment: I'll leave this question unanswered for the moment in case someone has a better idea.